# Are there any badges for reviewing documentation changes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation, review-queues, badges

When reviewing for example Triage, First Posts or Late Answers, it it possible to earn badges such as Custodian, Reviewer and Steward. These badges are visible in the stats tab of the review and in Badge Progress bar:

[image: badges]

However, in the documentation review, there is neither any stats tab nor any Badge Progress bar.

My question is if there are any badges that can be earned by reviewing documentation changes, other than the [Peer Review](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5854/peer-review) badge, which is awarded for the first review of a documentation change (I looked in the [badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) and only found the Peer Review badge that could be a such badge). If that is not the case, I think that it would be a good idea to create such badges, since they would encourage people to review documentation changes in the same way as the Reviewer and Steward badges encourage people to review other reviews.